# Boot up Nexus 7 through induction charging

Tags: nexus-7, boot, wireless-charging

I have Nexus 7 (2013, rooted). I have seen plenty of examples of people being able to successfully modify Android system scripts such as `chargemon` to essentially hijack the few scripts running when an Android device is turned off, but plugged in through USB to charge. However, it doesn't seem that induction charging is able to offer any kind of trigger that can be taken advantage of to automatically boot up the device. Is it possible to achieve this goal without a factory hardware set, no modifications?

I'm not a hardware guy, so I really don't know anything about what I could/should do in that respect, but if hardware changes are my only option then it's not something I wouldn't look into. Are there even hardware modifications that could be possible to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution for the following problem:

- The Nexus 7 (2013) device must never be turned off unless it has an insufficient amount of power.
- When the Nexus 7 (2013) device is exposed to an inductive charge, it should turn on automatically.

In order to apply this change to my device, I activated the bootloader and ran a simple batch file with the following script:

```
fastboot oem unlock
fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0
fastboot oem lock
fastboot reboot
```

This line:

```
fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0
```

sets the device to turn on whenever there is enough charge remaining that is sufficient to power up the device. If the device is drained completely of battery, then charged via conduction to or above a level of sufficient battery for rebooting, it will not reboot unless it is then either the charger is removed and re-applied or if the power button is pressed. This means that if a device is charged from 0% battery to 100% battery and removed from the charger, it can remain turned off for shipment until it arrives at its destination, in which it can be touched to an inductive charger and instantly turned on with no power button interaction whatsoever.

Comment: Is this mode sticky, or does it only work once?